# How to get the id of the button where the user clicked?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, button

I'm trying to get the id of the button where the user clicked but it's returning undefined.
Here is my code :

```js
let btnvot = document.createElement('button');
btnvot.className = "btn btn-primary spacing";
btnvot.innerText = "Voter";
btnvot.id = doc.id;
btnvot.onclick = addvote();

function addvote(){
alert(this.id);
}
```

but when the page is loading its writing undefined in the pop up box

Can someone help me ?

Comment: Use `event.currentTarget.id`

Comment: `btnvot.onclick = addvote;`

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying on HTML. May be you can try this

```html
<button id="id1" onClick="displayBtnId(this.id)">Button 1</button>
<button id="id2" onClick="displayBtnId(this.id)">Button 2</button>
<button id="id3" onClick="displayBtnId(this.id)">Button 3</button>
    
<script>
  function displayBtnId(clickedBtnid)
  {
      alert(clickedBtnid);
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
let btnvot = document.createElement('button');
btnvot.className = "btn btn-primary spacing";
btnvot.innerText = "Voter";
btnvot.id = "abc";
btnvot.onclick = addvote;

function addvote() {
  alert(this.id);
}

document.body.appendChild(btnvot);
```

Comment: `this` will point to the element itself if the event is called correctly. No need for e.target.id;